# Multiple inheritance for the Lookup lists. is this supported

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, spfieldlookupvalue

I have 3 lists as follow:-

1. ItemCategory
2. Item
3. Invoice

the Item list has a lookup field to the ItemCategory list

the Invoice list has a lookup field to the Item list.

now i am trying to get the ItemCategory title inside the Invoice list, but seems this is not available, as follow:-

[image]

the only work around i find is to add a lookup field to the Invoice list as well, which reference the ItemCategory,, but in this case i will have duplicate info for the Item and its Category (one inside the Item list and the other inside the Invoice list!!).. any advice?

Comment: I would merge ItemCategory and Item into one list, that's, add a Category column in Item list.

Comment: @MatiurRahman ok let say i did so,, then how i can get the ItemCategory inside the Invoice list (which is my main question), where as shown in the screen shot i provided the lookup column inside the Item list (lookup to the ItemCategory list) can not be selected (similar to the Title, Id, Created,version,etc..) when creating the lookup between the Invoice and the Item lists... did you get my point?

Answer (score 1):

Lookup column does not have a transfer inheritance relationship. You could merge ItemCategory list and Item list.

Comment: ok let say i did so,, then how i can get the ItemCategory inside the Invoice list under the additional fields (which is my main question), where as shown in the screen shot i provided the lookup column inside the Item list (lookup to the ItemCategory list) can not be selected (similar to the Title, Id, Created,version,etc..) when creating the lookup between the Invoice and the Item lists... did you get my point?

Comment: Lookup column cannot be selected in the additional fields by default.

Comment: @ Emily Du - MSFT thanks ,, but can you advice more on what you mean by "By default"?can i have any workarounds?

Comment: You could create a single line of text column in the Item list. Text column have the same value as lookup column. Then use text column in the additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Items list showing ItemTitle and ItemCategory**

[image]

**Create a Lookup Column** (ItemOrdered) in **Invoice** list pointing to Items list
showing **ItemTitle** and **ItemCategory** in Invoice list

[image]

**Invoice List Showing ItemTitle and ItemCategory**

[image]

Comment: but in my case the ItemCategory need to be a lookup field and not a single line of text field..this is my main issue..

Comment: As you already know, SP can't model data as SQL Server does. Is there a reason that "Category" needs to be a look up column in Item list?

Comment: yes so if i delete an itemcategory then all the items will be removed, also if i updated the itemcatgory title it will get reflected inside all the items' categories, also i am using the ItemCategory on other lists, and so on..